# ValueError: Tensor's shape (26, 400) is not compatible with supplied shape [26, 200]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, keras-tuner

I am working on training a neural network using `keras` and `keras_tuner` for hyper parameter tuning and ran into an error that isn't similar to other questions asked in the website before.

Here's the code that is relevant according to my knowledge:

1. **Splitting my Dataset**

```
x = data.drop('label', axis=1).values
X = normalize(x)
y = pd.get_dummies(data['label']).values
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=40)
print("Length of train set: ", X_train.shape, "y:", y_train.shape)
print("Length of test set: ", X_test.shape, "y:", y_test.shape)
```

which resulted like this:

```
Length of train set:  (7922, 26) y: (7922, 6)
Length of test set:  (3396, 26) y: (3396, 6)
```

2. **Building my Model**

```
def build_model(hp):
    model = Sequential()
    step = 100
    for i in range(hp.Int('num_layers', 3, 4)):
        if i == 1:
            model.add(
                Dense(
                    units=hp.Int('units_'+str(i), min_value=step*2, max_value=step*5, default=step*2, step=step),
                    input_dim=26,
                    activation=hp.Choice('dense_activation_'+str(i), values=['relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid'])
                )
            )
        else:
            model.add(
                Dense(units=hp.Int('units_' + str(i), min_value=step*2, max_value=step*5, default=step*2, step=step),
                      activation=hp.Choice('dense_activation_'+str(i), values=['relu', 'tanh', 'sigmoid'])
                      )
            )
        model.add(
            Dropout(
                hp.Float('dropout_' + str(i), min_value=0.0, max_value=0.1, default=0.1, step=0.02)
            )
        )
        if step > 20:
            step = step/2
        else:
            step = 10

    model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
    # optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

3. **Using Hyperband to hypertune the Parameters**

```
tuner = kt.Hyperband(
    build_model,
    max_epochs=100,
    objective='accuracy',
    seed=42,
    executions_per_trial=2
)
tuner.search(X_train, y_train, epochs=500, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
best_model = tuner.get_best_models()[0]
```

and Finally after all that i got an error which is as shown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PycharmProjects\FYP_Project\Keras training\Keras Training.py", line 75, in <module>
    best_model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)[1] * 100)
  File "AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1489, in evaluate
    tmp_logs = self.test_function(iterator)
  File "AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 889, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 933, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 763, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3050, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3444, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3279, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 999, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 672, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 986, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1323 test_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1314 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1285 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3608 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1307 run_step  **
        outputs = model.test_step(data)
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:1266 test_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=False)
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:1030 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py:394 call
        outputs = layer(inputs, **kwargs)
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:1023 __call__
        self._maybe_build(inputs)
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:2625 _maybe_build
        self.build(input_shapes)  # pylint:disable=not-callable
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py:1191 build
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:639 add_weight
        variable = self._add_variable_with_custom_getter(
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py:810 _add_variable_with_custom_getter
        new_variable = getter(
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer_utils.py:127 make_variable
        return tf_variables.VariableV1(
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py:260 __call__
        return cls._variable_v1_call(*args, **kwargs)
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py:206 _variable_v1_call
        return previous_getter(
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py:67 getter
        return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3523 creator
        return next_creator(**kwargs)
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py:67 getter
        return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\Axell\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3523 creator
        return next_creator(**kwargs)
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py:67 getter
        return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3523 creator
        return next_creator(**kwargs)
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py:67 getter
        return captured_getter(captured_previous, **kwargs)
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py:750 variable_capturing_scope
        v = UnliftedInitializerVariable(
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py:264 __call__
        return super(VariableMetaclass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py:293 __init__
        initial_value = initial_value()
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py:86 __call__
        return CheckpointInitialValue(
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py:122 __init__
        self.wrapped_value.set_shape(shape)
    AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:1238 set_shape
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Tensor's shape (26, 400) is not compatible with supplied shape [26, 200]
```

I'm not even sure where the 400 came from, and i realized that i have a zero on one of my layer, but when i remove that, the error still stayed the same.
the new changes i've made are:

```
def build_model(hp):
    model = Sequential()
    for i in range(hp.Int('num_layers', 4, 5)):
        # if i == 1:
        #     model.add(Dense(units=hp.Int('units_' + str(i),
        #                                  min_value=20,
        #                                  max_value=500,
        #                                  step=20),
        #                     input_dim=26,
        #                     activation='relu'))
        # else:
            model.add(Dense(units=hp.Int('units_' + str(i),
                                                min_value=20,
                                                max_value=500,
                                                step=20),
                                   activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
    # optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(
            hp.Choice('learning_rate', [1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])), metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Still had the 400 from somewhere, can someone enlighten me of where it comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is bug with Keras tuner, I found the similar issue when getting the best model as below:

```
models = tuner.get_best_models(num_models=2) 
best_model = models[0]
best_model.build(input_shape=(INPUT_FEATURE_SIZE, ))
```

This problem can be solved by using **get_best_hyperparameters()** method as below:

```
best_hp = tuner.get_best_hyperparameters()[0]
best_model = tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hp)
print("Best Model summary is as below: ")
best_model.summary()
```